# What is the maximum Length of URI string generated by Microsoft Push Notification Services?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Can somebody guide me about the length of generated URI from Microsoft PUSH Notification Services?

I am getting the URL string Length of 120. I just want to make sure that whenever my Windows phone app will receive a new URI from MPNS, it would always be 120 bytes in length. If it can be longer, then how long can it be?

Comment: That comment is not helpful. I Googled it too, and couldn't find an answer. I'm also getting a URL of 120 characters.

Answer (score 3):

Channel URIs may be up to 1,024 characters long.

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/10/22/recommended-practices-for-using-microsoft-push-notification-service-mpns.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

In the field of mobile browsing, URL limitation can be much lower. Many handsets still don’t support URLs longer than 128, 256 or 512 characters, in particular WAP devices (as opposed to devices carrying a full blown HTTP browser)
i suggest u use 256 characters

Comment: OP asked for the maximum length of the URI retrieved from Microsoft Push Notification Service.  The length supported by Internet Explorer or a by a mobile browser is irrelevant in this case as the URI retrieved is handled in code and usually stored in a server-side database to enable notifications to be sent to users devices